# JTable selection listener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

I have a code which displays Table in applets & consists of two columns:-

1. image icon
2. description

Here's my code:

```
    import javax.swing.table.*;

    public class TableIcon extends JFrame
     {
    public TableIcon()
    {
    ImageIcon aboutIcon = new ImageIcon("about16.gif");
    ImageIcon addIcon = new ImageIcon("add16.gif");
    ImageIcon copyIcon = new ImageIcon("copy16.gif");

    String[] columnNames = {"Picture", "Description"};
    Object[][] data =
    {
        {aboutIcon, "About"},
        {addIcon, "Add"},
        {copyIcon, "Copy"},
    };

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    JTable table = new JTable( model )
    {
        //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
        //  renderers to be used based on Class
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
    getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    TableIcon frame = new TableIcon();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

Now what i want to know is how can I implement selection listener or mouse listener event on my table , such that it should select a particular image from my table and display on text area or text field(my table contains path of image file)?

Can I add text field on table & table on frame?  Please feel free to ask queries if required.

Answer (score 8):

In my code I have a table where I set single selection mode; in my case, listener described  in [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) (with a for loop from getMinSelectionIndex to getMaxSelectionIndex) is not useful because releasing mouse button I'm sure I have just one row selected.

So I've solved as follows:

```
....

int iSelectedIndex =-1;

....

JTable jtable = new JTable(tableModel); // tableModel defined elsewhere
jtable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

ListSelectionModel selectionModel = jtable.getSelectionModel();

selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        handleSelectionEvent(e);
    }
});

....

protected void handleSelectionEvent(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if (e.getValueIsAdjusting())
        return;

    // e.getSource() returns an object like this
    // javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel 1052752867 ={11}
    // where 11 is the index of selected element when mouse button is released

    String strSource= e.getSource().toString();
    int start = strSource.indexOf("{")+1,
        stop  = strSource.length()-1;
    iSelectedIndex = Integer.parseInt(strSource.substring(start, stop));
}
```

I think this solution, that does not require a for loop between start and stop to check which element is selectes, is more suitable when table is in single selection mode

Comment: Please don't do that! If the table is in single selection mode, the `e.getFirstIndex()` or `e.getLastIndex()` will give you the selected line.
Then call any method of `ListSelectionModel`, like `((ListSelectionModel)e.getSource()).isSelectedIndex(e.getFirstIndex())` for example. For the sake of code understandability...

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
        protected void handleSelectionEvent(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (e.getValueIsAdjusting())
                return;

            final DefaultListSelectionModel target = (DefaultListSelectionModel)e.getSource();
            iSelectedIndex = target.getAnchorSelectionIndex();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html).

You can't add a text field to the table, but you can add a textfield and a table to the same frame.

Comment: or he can trigger the edition of a given cell of the table to make a textfield appear. The requirement is unclear to me.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet i am more concerned about adding action listener to my table that's it

Comment: There is no ActionListener for a table.